# how to handle play database connection exceptions

Tags: java, playframework

I’m doing a research for my project about to select the best java-based MVC framework that fits the needs of my team to develop web apps. Play framework is at the moment the best choice; is really lightweight, and has a low learning curve because of its simplicity and friendly approach. I’m using Play Framework version 2.2.1 with Ebean.
But there’s only one thing that got me stuck, let me describe my problem:

My application has several DB servers configured because it can switch connection between them. But when one or more of them are down the play framework throws an exception at the first http request. It throws the exception even before executing my Controller action code. That’s not what I desire, I expect to have control over the exception and serve my index.html view with some cache data and some user friendly message.

When Play receive the first http request then try to create a DB transaction and get a connection from the connection pool. I don’t want that. I want to control when Play should handle a transaction for me and avoid default transactions handle.

Please if someone can help me I’ll be truly thankful.